# SonarQube rulesets present in projects but nothing gets generated in code analysis

Tags: c#, asp.net, sonarqube, code-analysis

I have a C# silverlight project where I am trying to perform code analysis with SonarQube. Project is successfully bound to the sonarQube but in code analysis there is nothing that gets registered against sonarQube rulesets. Can anyone guide here.

Comment: do you have the sonarqube output?

Comment: Hey @EamonnMcEvoy. I am not getting any warnings from sonarqube ruleset. Its just the regular c# ones(with CA, CS code and not with S100,S1006 from sonar).

Comment: Post the console output here, it might reveal something. I had some issues with my c# project and was able to resolve it but you will need to examine the logs. Could your issue be similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783418/sonarqube-producing-different-results-in-different-folders/48792821#48792821? I didn't have any warnings either, just no results. It was caused by the casing in my folder names.

Comment: @AakashThakur please, run the analysis with `/d:sonar.verbose=true` argument on the `begin` step. Instead of posting the logs here (as they could be big) you could use [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/request/CszJAO1ZNXFVl1gwo5hA). If I receive them I'll write here again.